# Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix error - but I have the attribute?

Tags: android, xml

I have this in my res/drawable folder, and it has been working for the past few weeks. Today I went to build the project, and it throws "Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix" even though I have the prefix in the document. I have also tried adding the tools one as well, but that doesn't work either.

I have cleaned the project, restarted Eclipse and nothing seems to be working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape type="rectangle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke android:width="1.0px" android:color="#ffffffff" />
    <solid android:color="#ffffffff" />
    <corners android:radius="5.0dip" />
</shape>
```

Comment: You sure that it is from that xml?

Comment: Just make sure that `<?xml ........ >` is at the first line in xml.